# What limits the speed at which elastic materials contract or expand?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, viscosity

Suppose a material is fixed at one end and stretched with a force within its elastic limit (so no permanent deformation occurs), what happens internally when the force is instantaneously released?

Even though the stress was uniformly spread along the material, presumably the molecules nearer the fixed point cannot instantaneously know that the force no longer exists at the other end. My intuition is that a wavefront occurs in the material, starting at the released end and propagating at the speed of sound (for the material), until it reaches the fixed end (and reflects?) - but I haven't been able to find any confirmation of this.

Is this the case? And if so, does this limit the maximum contraction rate of the material to the speed of sound, or does the contraction rate depend upon other aspects of the material?

The reason I'm asking is to try to get a better understanding of what the limiting factors are of a projectile being launched from an elastic material. Assuming the elastic energy is all converted to kinetic energy for the projectile, what limits the maximum launch speed?

Comment: Related to [the rebound speed of silicone](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285186). ... Your question is good until the last sentence. *Assuming the elastic energy is all converted to KE for the projectile* determines what the launch speed will be, avoiding the complications of the previous paragraphs - ie the visco-elastic response of the stretched material.

Comment: @sammygerbil ah yes, I probably could have phrased it a bit better. Of course, I meant any *additional* energy not consumed by the contracting material would be converted to kinetic energy. I was trying to get away from issues like air resistance causing a loss of speed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by elastic limit? If it can be described by Hooke's law " _exactly_ ", then the contraction/expansion is " _instantaneous_ " (consider that in rheology, this only means "faster than the time resolution of my experiment") - if not, it is not within the elastic limit as I understand the term. So well ... I'm confused here :)