# What limits the projectile speed and power of a ballista?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity

Suppose that I have arbitrary quantities of some material A, a string material B, and I make a gigantic crossbow/ballista out of it, making an arm out of A and the string out of B.

What happens as I scale up the dimensions of this ballista? Can I scale things up proportionately indefinitely and shoot the projectile out faster and faster? (until the speed of light?)

Do I need to increase the relative thickness of the arms to have them not snap?

Is there some limit to the speed and size of the projectile that I would reach even with unlimited resources?

Comment: I am aware that https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323693/ is a similar question, but apparently that question was worded improperly and so unanswered. This is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Since the crossbow consists of an elastic rod and string, the question of the maximum velocity of the projectile is addressed to the question of the maximum speed with which the curved rod is straightened. There is an obvious limit that is [the speed of flexural vibrations](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/112105054/ADG_Final/lec24.pdf). In the Euler-Bernoulli model, this speed can be estimated as $c_b\sqrt {\frac {E}{\rho }}\frac {r_b}{L_b}$. Here $E$ is the modulus of elasticity, $\rho $ is the density, $r_b,L_b$ is the radius and length of the rod, respectively. The constant $c_b$ is of the order of unity. When we increase the scale of the system speed limit does not change.